# Prove that $(X_1 X_2\cdots X_n)^{1/n} \to c$ as $n\to\infty$ where $c$ is a constant

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables

[image]
This is a assignment question, a part of my homework. So I need hints to start towards the solution. I was thinking that under the given conditions of the problem the random variables $\log X_1$, $\log X_2$, $\log X_3$ can be considered to be independent and identically distributed. I also tried to refer to [law of large numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers), but could not get any ideas from there. I am novice at this topic, so any hints, suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: @akkkk Eaagh! Please don't.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The law of large numbers deals with (normalized) sums of random variables. Hence, if indeed one wants to use it, one should first transform the random variables of interest into sums. At present, these random variables are, roughly speaking, products. Fortunately, you already noticed that the logarithm transforms products into sums. Thus, ...

(To help you check your result, $c=96^{1/6}$.)